# Powershell command to Change Public Access of Data Factory from Enable to Disabled

Tags: azure, powershell, networking, azure-data-factory

Powershell command to Change Public Access of Data Factory from `Enabled` to `Disabled`.
This is coming under the `Networking` options of the Data Factory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the command below, it works on my side.

```
$factory = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DataFactory/factories -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -ResourceName <datafactory-name>
$factory.Properties.publicNetworkAccess = "Disabled"
$factory | Set-AzResource -Force
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

**Update:**

You could use the command below, no matter you have changed the setting or not.

```
$factory = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DataFactory/factories -ResourceGroupName "<resource-group-name>" -ResourceName "<datafactory-name>"
$factory.Properties | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "publicNetworkAccess" -Value "Disabled" -Force
$factory | Set-AzResource -Force
```

[image]

Comment: Can we connect over Phone/email to get this sorted. I have tried this command I got it that it will fetch the required outputs but there is an error message and issues as below: Error message- $a.Properties.publicNetworkAccess = "Disabled" SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "publicNetworkAccess": "The property 'publicNetworkAccess' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Comment: Below message- PS /home/bragaa06> $factory = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DataFactory/factories -ResourceGroupName ControlsAndCompliance-rg-dev -ResourceName testpscodenetwork

PS /home/bragaa06> $factory.Properties.publicNetworkAccess = "Disabled"

SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "publicNetworkAccess": "The property 'publicNetworkAccess' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Comment: We are using below PS version. Name Value ---- ----- PSVersion 7.0.3 PSEdition Core We are trying it from Azure Powershell itself & we are not getting any error related to the module.

Comment: we have urgent requirement if you can help quick that will be great. Kindly let us know exactly how we can extract the property of 'publicNetworkAccess' from the $a object.

Comment: @AnirudhB Is `testpscodenetwork` the name of your datafactory? Judging from its naming, it seems not like a datafactory?

Comment: yes that the data factory resource name. But if I run the Above script there is a message which it gives which I have shared above.and that error message of property comes when executed the second line. $factory.Properties.publicNetworkAccess = "Disabled" SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "publicNetworkAccess": "The property 'publicNetworkAccess' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Comment: @AnirudhBa Can you make sure you used the script totally the same as mine? I also test it in powershell 7, it works fine.

Comment: it's great your quickly responding thanks a lot. Yes it is the same total script used copied and pasted and then executed.Now the script which is being executed is in directly in azure powershell that is from portal.

Comment: @AnirudhB You mean you run the powershell in azure cloud shell? I also test it, it works, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKwtX.png

Comment: @AnirudhB Try to use `""` to enclose your group name and factory name.

Comment: I dint try enclosing as you said, will try it .But are you sure it is only that problem based on the above error message.yes I m trying from azure cloudshell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221902/discussion-between-anirudh-b-and-joy-wang).

Comment: Can you Pls help me in understanding what was the difference in older one and newer one technically

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time in helping me for the subjected issue. Now with the updated script which you gave We are able to get the expected result. marked as perfect answer.

Comment: Hi Joy, I tried the script 1, the same error with Anirudh, then I tried script 2 ,it shows " Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null." How can I solve this? Thx